# M2Mqtt in C# is not connected, doesn't give data

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I have a project creating a websocket client side (Subscriber) to a MQTT publisher. I am quite new to C# and MQTT protocol. I follow some youtube video to make finish my very first lines connecting to this MQTT publisher to get all the train going in and out Helsinki station.

- broker: "rata.digitraffic.fi"
- Port: 80
- Topic: trains-by-station/HKI (HKI abbr for Helsinki)

I use M2Mqtt library in dotnet to build the subscriber, somehow the client_MqttMsgPublishReceived function is never triggered. the `client.IsConnected` always returned false value!
You can find info of this mqtt protocol in the url below.

https://www.digitraffic.fi/rautatieliikenne/#websocket-mqtt

It gives me example in JavaScripts and it seems to run fine with the example of each MQTT. But when I tried to do it with my PC, it doesn't give me any thing, but

```
Hello World!!!
False
```

and the cmd window on hold.
SOOOO FRUSTRATING right now. it would be much appreciate if anyone can help me out.
BTW, I am using win10, I tried with dotnet 4/5/6 and m2mqtt 4.3.0.

```
using System.Text;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;
using System;

namespace m2qttSubscriber
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!!!!");
            MqttClient client = new MqttClient("rata.digitraffic.fi", 
                                               80,
                                               false,
                                               MqttSslProtocols.None,
                                               null,
                                               null);

            client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;

            string clientID = "myclientid_" + RandomDigits(4);
            client.Connect(clientID);
            Console.WriteLine(client.IsConnected);
            client.Subscribe(new string[] { "trains-by-station/HKI" },
                             new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_MOST_ONCE}) ;
        }
        static void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SOme thing is received");
            string payload = Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Recevied {0} from", payload);
        }
        static public string RandomDigits(int length)
        {
            var random = new Random();

            string s = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                s = String.Concat(s, random.Next(10).ToString());
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt` supports [MQTT over Websockets](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt/issues/70); try using `rata-mqtt.digitraffic.fi:1883` (MQTT over standard TCP) or using an [alternate library](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/master/Samples/Client/Client_Connection_Samples.cs#L136).

Comment: Oh. thank you. I change the code to `MqttClient client = new MqttClient("rata-mqtt.digitraffic.fi", 1883, false, MqttSslProtocols.None, null, null);` and it works now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments the library used (`uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt`) [does not support](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt/issues/70) [MQTT over Websockets](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718127) (which is what `rata.digitraffic.fi:80` offers).

If you are able to use standard MQTT (over TCP/IP) then `rata-mqtt.digitraffic.fi:1883` works (OP succeeded with `MqttClient client = new MqttClient("rata-mqtt.digitraffic.fi", 1883, false, MqttSslProtocols.None, null, null);`) and this is generally preferable to using WebSockets (there are some situations where you have to use WebSockets; e.g. code running in a browser or to bypass some filters/proxies).

Alternatively there are [other libraries](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/master/Samples/Client/Client_Connection_Samples.cs#L136) that do offer support for MQTT over Websockets.